# Laravel eloquent query having JOIN and subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have to use a query in Laravel eloquent ([query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)) but I'm not sure how to convert it:

```
SELECT c.*, m.*,th.team as team_home, ta.team as team_away from schedule as c

LEFT JOIN matches as m ON m.id_match = c.match_id
LEFT JOIN teams as  th ON m.team_h = th.id_team
LEFT JOIN teams as  ta ON m.team_a = ta.id_team

WHERE c.serie_id = :sid and c.days =(

   SELECT c.days from schedule as c
   LEFT JOIN matches as m ON m.id_match = c.match_id
   WHERE c.serie_id = :sid and m.match_stato = 2 order by c.days DESC LIMIT 1

) order by c.days, th.team ASC
```

As you noticed it has 3 JOINS and a subquery than two orders. How can I use it in Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

For subqueries of that nature, you can use `whereIn()`.

Also, for the logic inside the subquery, instead of `order by c.days DESC LIMIT 1`, you can just use `max(c.days)` in the select clause.

```
DB::table('schedule as c')
    ->join('matches as m', 'm.id_match', '=', 'c.match_id')
    ->join('teams as th', 'm.team_h', '=', 'th.id_team')
    ->join('teams as ta', 'm.team_a', '=', 'ta.id_team')

    ->where('c.serie_id', '=', $sid)
    ->whereIn('c.days', function($query) use($sid){
        $query->select('max(c.days)')
            ->from('schedule as c2')
            ->join('matches as m2', 'm2.id_match', '=', 'c2.match_id')
            ->where('c2.serie_id', '=', $sid)
            ->where('m2.match_stato', '=', 2);
    }) 
    ->select('c.*', 'm.*', 'th.team as team_home', 'ta.team as team_away')

    ->orderBy('c.days', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('th.team', 'asc')
    ->get();      

######
```

Comment: Thanks Augusto! Very helpfull too! This is very helpful and well formatted! But it gets an error using MAX() in the subquery, it returns not the max value but the column name:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'max(c2.days)'

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. Double check any errors or logic as it was quite a convoluted query. But i am hoping it will give you the pointers in right direction

```
DB::query()
   ->select(['c.*', 'm.*','th.team as team_home', 'ta.team as team_away'])
   ->from('schedules AS c')
   ->leftJoin('matches AS m', 'm.id_match', '=', 'c.match_id')
   ->leftJoin('teams AS th', 'm.team_h', '=', 'th.id_team')
   ->leftJoin('teams AS ta', 'm.team_a', '=', 'ta.id_team')

   ->where('c.serie_id','=',':sid')
   ->whereIn('c.days', function($q) {
       $q->select('c.days')
         ->from('schedule AS c')
         ->leftJoin('matches AS m', 'm.id_match', '=', 'c.match_id')
          ->where('c.serie_id','=',':sid')
          ->where('m.match_stato','=',2)
          ->orderBy('c.days','DESC')
          ->limit(1);
     })

    ->orderBy('c.days')
    ->get()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful! But I get an error using LIMIT in the subquery: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'